# Java Interface Method call

Tags: java

I have a Java interface as below

```
public interface IFilter 
{
    public void doFilter();           
}
```

I have an implementation of this interface as `Filter1, Filter2, ...`. I am adding these implementations to a `List<IFilter>`.

```
 private final List<IFilter> filterChain = new ArrayList<>();
```

Following is the sample impl class

```
public class FirstFilter implements IFilter
{
    private String name = "first";

    @Override
    public void doFilter()
    {
        System.out.println("First Filter !");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return super.equals(obj); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return super.hashCode(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

And I am iterating over this list to call `doFilter()`.

```
public void filter()
{
     for(IFilter filter: filterChain)
     {
         filter.doFilter();
     }
}
```

But this gives an error

> cannot find symbol filter.doFilter();
>   symbol:   method doFilter()
>   location: variable filter of type IFilter where IFilter is a
>   type-variable:
>   IFilter extends Object declared in class FilterChain 1 error

I am not able to understand whats going wrong here?

Comment: Can you show your Filter1/Filter2 classes?

Comment: How do you compile? Command line or IDE? Did you ensure that you have compiled all related source files? Ideally you should not only provide code snippets, but a [mcve]

Comment: check imports, possible you are importing `IFilter` from another package

Comment: This is definitely not a code issue.

Comment: I have tested this code in Intelij and Netbeans IDE as well as compiled it from cmd.

Comment: What class is that `filter` method in?  Did you declare it as a generic with `IFilter` as a type parameter?  If so, then your type parameter has overridden the `IFilter` interface.  Use a different symbol as your type parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note

> where IFilter is a type-variable

I.e. you have something like

```
class FilterChain<IFilter> {
    ...
    public void filter() 
    {
         for(IFilter filter: filterChain)
         {
             filter.doFilter();
         }
    }
}
```

Here `IFilter` doesn't refer to the interface `IFilter`, but to the type parameter; it's exactly equivalent to

```
class FilterChain<T> {
    ...
    public void filter() 
    {
         for(T filter: filterChain)
         {
             filter.doFilter();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, its not working that way either ! The problem is it is not able to recognize doFilter() method from interface.

Comment: @user34567: As mentioned before by others: please show us your class `FilterChain` that implements the method `filter`

Comment: "No, its not working that way either !" Yes, the point it is to explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Got it ! I have removed type declaration and its working now.